# Iterate over object with correct generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I want to iterate over a generic interface. And use the value of the object in jsx. But Typescript throws the following:

> Argument of type '(key: K) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) =>
> Element'.

```
interface Props<T> {
  object: T;
}

export default function BasicInputs<T, K extends keyof T>({
  object,
}: Props<T>): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(object).map((key: K) => (
        <div>
          <div className="">
            <input
              value={object[key]}
              type="text"
              name="name"
              id="name"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How should I define the interface and component for correct typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input />` expects `value` to be `string | number | readonly string[] | undefined`.

We can obtain valid `input.value` type in this way:

```js
type InputValue = React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>['value']
```

Now we need just to apply appropriate restriction to `T`:

```js
type InputValue = React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>['value']

type HashMap = Record<PropertyKey, InputValue>

interface Props<T> {
  object: T;
}

export default function BasicInputs<T extends HashMap>({
  object,
}: Props<T>) {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(object).map((key) => (
        <div>
          <div className="">
            <input
              value={object[key]}
              type="text"
              name="name"
              id="name"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It should work.